# RSpec with Factory_girl - destroy object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

I wan't to test a relationship between two Models. 
`A course has many enrollments, an enrollment has one course.`

When a course is being destroyed, all enrolments connected to it are being set to `active = false`. This works with real objects, I just can't get the test to work because no matter what I do, the course isn't being destroyed.

```
describe Enrollment do
  it "deactivates enrollment" do
    course = create(:a_course)
    user = create_user
    enrollment = build(:enrollment)
    enrollment.course = course
    enrollment.user = user
    enrollment.save

    # until now everything works as expected

    expect { course.destroy }.to change { enrollment.active }.to be_false

    # the course isn't being destroyed when calling course.destroy

  end
end
```

I couldn't find anything about destroying a factory_girl object in the factory_girl docs, maybe I'm doing it all wrong and I should use "real" objects? Thanks!

**Update**
Here is the model where the change happens

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...

  has_many :users, through: :enrollments
  has_many :enrollments

  before_destroy :deactivate_enrollments

  protected

  def deactivate_enrollments
    enrollments = self.enrollments

    enrollments.each do |e|
      e.active = false
      e.save
    end
  end
end
```

As I'm not really sure about this, the course I'm using to test with is a factory_girl object. It's not created like this: `Course.create...`. Does the factory_girl object have the same methods as the ActiveRecord object?

Here is the `factory_girl` code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :course, class: Course do
    titel "Course title"
  end
end
```

**Update 2**
Here is the `failure message`

```
Enrollment
  deactivates enrolment (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Enrollment deactivates enrollment
     Failure/Error: expect { course.destroy }.to change(enrollment, :active).from(true).to(false)
       active should have been changed to false, but is now true
     # ./spec/models/enrollment_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Update 3**

It turns out, the course isn't being destroyed. Neither `Course.destroy_all` or `course.destroy` works. No matter if I create the course and enrollment with factory_girl or not. How can this be?

Comment: It would help to look at your model where you are changing the associated enrollments active status

Comment: I updated the original question and added the model @Vimsha.

Comment: did you stub the destroy method somewhere?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Could I test this somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I noticed that you answered your own question by reloading the enrollment but, even so, I think you should change your rspec syntax to be more readable and expressive. The final result could be:

```
expect { 
  course.destroy
  enrollment.reload
}.to change(enrollment, :active).from(true).to(false)
```

I think that would be a better way to document the behavior of your code, since it reads almost like fluent english ;)

Comment: Thanks but I got the same failure message, that it still is true. I as well tried to write `course.destroy` and then `expect(course).to be_nil` but that didn't work as well. Am I wrong thinking that factory_girl objects can generally be destroyed like this?

Comment: What is the failure message ?

Comment: No that didn't change anything.

Comment: Jeez. If you check the course's enrollments collection before destroying, it shows the how many items ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47526/discussion-between-guilherme-franco-and-linusan)

Comment: Sorry I'm not at my computer at the moment, I'll check when I'm back. Thanks!

Comment: When I'm now creating the records with ActiveRecord, the course is being deleted but the course model callback isn't firing.

Comment: Yes that works as well. You're right, and you gave me the hint with the reload, I'll accept your answer. Interesting that if I write it in one line, I need to put the commands in an array, which is not needed in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! It turns out I have to, after writing `course.destroy`, write `enrollment.reload` to be able to see any changes concerning the enrollment.

The test could then look like this:

```
expect { [course.destroy, enrollment.reload] }.to change { enrollment.active }.to be_false
```

Comment: That's great ! But, I still think that the syntax I purpose is more readable and is recommended in the rspec documentation. Could you try `expect { [course.destroy, enrollment.reload] }.to change(enrollment, :active).from(true).to(false)` please ? Then, I'll update my answer.